# IUnityContainer property is not resolved

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, prism

I am using `Unity` in a prism App and I am having a very weird issue with some properties of type `IUnityContainer` decorated with `Dependency` attribute, they are just not self instantiated.


Is there a logical reason for that?

Limitations I should consider?

I have learned that MEF and Unity mixing can lead to unresolved dependencies issue but this is not my case, I am only using Unity across my composite app.

Comment: Self-instantiated? Or injected upon resolving? A concrete example would help. Also, injecting the container using the container is a smell, possibly indicates bad design.

Comment: I meant injected upon resolving as I am resolving the class which contains the property in question. Though, I think you're right about bad design. I have a parent view model that has a constructor resolved container. and I have the child view model (in a collection ) that has a container property. I used it to resolve some repositories and services rather than putting them in the constructor.